# GoJS auto align Links?

Tags: gojs

Is it possible to enforce some kind of auto-alignment after the graph is created?

I use the `go.Model.fromJson()` method to create the edges like this:

```
go.Model.fromJson({
  nodeDataArray: [...],
  linkDataArray: [
    {
      from: 1,
      to: 2,
      text: "1 to 2"
    },
    ...
  ]
});
```

After that my graph looks like this:

[image]

So can we add some kind of mechanism that can try to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you describe the "problem" a little more clearly? That the labels are overlapping, or something else? What's an acceptable solution? That the links move farther apart?

Comment: Hi @SimonSarris yes my problem is that the labels are overlapping and therefore unreadable.

Comment: You could set or bind the Link.curviness to be specific values that are large enough to provide sufficient space between them.  But that's not a general solution for you.  We intend to work on a more general solution for a future release.

Answer (score 0):

I think the functionality that you want will be in version 1.6.  Alas, it's not ready yet for beta testing.